# Display dates using moment, webpack and locale from browser

Tags: javascript, date, webpack, locale

The environment is React, Webpack, in browser.
This code works:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString(window.navigator.language))
=> en-au 11/01/2019, 1:33:20 pm
```

But it provides no formatting control. This code works too:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/en-au'
import 'moment/locale/fr'

moment.locale(window.navigator.language)
console.log(moment().format('L LTS'))
=> en-au 11/01/2019 1:33:20 PM
```

So `moment` does everything I need, but this code only works in the US, Australia and France. It seems that Webpack 'shakes the tree' and eliminates all the other locales provided by `moment`, except those explicitly 'required'.

Questions:

- Have I understood correctly?
- Is this the 'right' way to do it?
- Is there a way to preload all/most/lots of locales without having to list them all?

---

To try this out, start with create-react-app and then add the above code. Test it with some locale not explicitly loaded (such as 'de'). In my testing moment will default to 'en' which is 'en-us'.

Comment: I'm actually experiencing it the other way around. moment library is not modular so when `import moment from 'moment'`. It include all the locales (checked by webpack-bundle-analyzer).

Comment: Dates should be expressed in unambiguous form, not some randomised form where the result may well be unknown. The language should be used only for the language, it should not be used to infer user preferences. The simplest unambiguous form uses a short month name and full year, or perhaps ISO 8601 form. What format should `new Date().toLocaleString('ee')` generate?

Comment: @lthh89vt: But did you try the code? See edit for suggestion how.

Comment: @RobG: Dates are expressed in ISO format, but displayed according to user locale. A locale such as 'en-us' is both a language and a region, and is perfect for choosing display preferences. Since 'ee' is not supported by moment, it will display in 'en', which is 'en-us'. None of which is relevant to the question.

Comment: The statement "*Dates are expressed in ISO format, but displayed according to user locale*" seems to be *non sequitur*. ISO 8601 defines a number of formats, the most commonly referenced here is YYYY-MM-DDTHH.mm.ssZ. ISO 639 language codes like 'en-us' define languages and dialects, not a regions or localities, and are not a reliable indicator of user preferences.

Comment: No, tags like "en-gb" and "de-ch" are not ISO 639, but they are locales as widely understood eg see https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale.

Comment: I haven't tried my code as don't really need the other locales. However, I guess webpack would still include all the locale files but it just not get loaded by moment.

However, trying to import from `moment/min/moment-with-locales`